# Python: log myobj.myprop even if myobj or myobj.myprop are None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm looking for a **shortcut** for:

```
name = ''
if myobj not None and myobj.name not None:
  name = myobj.name

date = ''
if myobj not None and myobj.date not None:
  date = myobj.date

logging.info('Something happened with %s at %s', name, date)
```

Something **like**:

```
logging.info('Something happened with %s at %s', none_as_empty_str(myobj.name), none_as_empty_str(myobj.date))
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: @khelwood Looks good, but what if `myobj` is None? My question wasn't precise enough, I updated it.

Comment: OK. How about `myobj and myobj.name or ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something relatively short, you could use:

```
myobj and myobj.name or ''
```

If `myobj` or `myobj.name` is None (or otherwise falsey), this will produce `''`.
Otherwise it will produce `myobj.name`.

Alternatively, your `none_as_empty_str` function is viable as long as you defer accessing the attribute until inside the function, or access it indirectly. That way, if `myobj` is None, you can get your empty string instead of an exception:

```
def none_as_empty_str(obj, attr):
    return getattr(obj, attr, None) or ''

logging.info('Something happened with %s at %s',
             none_as_empty_str(myobj, 'name'),
             none_as_empty_str(myobj, 'date'))
```